# Getting different home page based on the user's permission in WebApplication Wicket

Tags: java, web-applications, wicket

I'm designing a tool where home page can be 2 different homepages with a completely different design and functionality. I know that we can normally set the home page using:

```
    public Class getHomePage() {
    return MyHomePage.class;
}
```

What is the efficient way to use a boolean to check the user's permission? Here is my basic idea:

```
        public Class getHomePage() {

           if(admin)
               return AdminPage.class;
           else
               return MyHomePage.class; 
    }
```

However, I still need to use a specific page for other configurations in init(), for example:

```
    getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(MyHomePage.class);
    getApplicationSettings().setAccessDeniedPage(MyHomePage.class);
    getApplicationSettings().setInternalErrorPage(MyHomePage.class);
```

What would be the best approach to tackle this?

Comment: What's the problem with what you have? Would you also like these three error pages to be the admin page if admin is true? What prevents you from doing it?

Comment: Yes that's right. I'm worried about the best practice. This is because I need to call isAdmin() from an authorization class in api and I'm not entirely sure whether I would break a good best practice rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 3 pages, one for non-admin users, one for admin users, and one (which could be used as the home/error page) that just redirect to one of the former.